# laravel 5.4 file validation don't break on single mismatch

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm building a file upload in which the user can upload multiple files. In this system, only images are allowed, the images should meet certain requirements before they're allowed in the system.
So I have a bit of validation on that form field by doing this:

```
$this->validate( $request, [
            'files.*'      => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tiff,psd,bmp|customValidator'
        ] );
```

What I want is that the validation doesn't break when a single file doesn't match. It should add all files except the files that don't match.

For example:
When I upload 19 images and one pdf, all 19 images should be added to the system and I should be notified (on screen) that my pdf was rejected.
Is that possible within this validation or should I do something different?

Comment: Instead of validating a whole request, use a loop to check each individual file.

Comment: I agree with @aynber. Validate each file individually and build an array of files which failed the validation.

Comment: Ah, I thought so myself already that it wasn't really logical to put it into the validator. Is there a way to call the validator for each file?

Comment: Pass in the file array/object instead of `$request` inside of your loop. You'll also need to tweak the validator to use something else instead of `files.*`